# How to connect to PHP fsockopen?

Tags: php, email, smtp, ubuntu-18.04

I am getting the error while connecting to fsockopen.

```
echo $result = fsockopen('ssl://smtp.gmail.com', 465, $error_no, $error_message, 5);
//$result = fsockopen('tls://smtp.gmail.com', 587, $error_no, $error_message, 5);
if ($result === false) {
  echo "error no: $error_no error message: $error_message";
  echo print_r($result, true);
} else {
  echo 'success';
}
```

> error no: 0 error message:

I checked the manual [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) which says

> If the value returned in errno is 0 and the function returned
> false, it is an indication that the error occurred before the
> connect() call. This is most likely due to a problem initializing the
> socket.

But I do not know how to resolve this. I have an AWS Ubuntu 18.04 instance and the website is https.

The problem is I am trying to set up gmail smtp. This settings works fine on local as well as other AWS instances where SSL isn't installed

**UPDATE:**

Solved it by  making sure that that OpenSSL was installed on my machine and then adding this to php.ini:

```
openssl.cafile=/etc/ssl/cacert.pem
```

Downloaded cacert.pem file by running below command.

```
wget --no-check-certificate  http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

Comment: Why are you trying to talk to Gmail (or any SMTP server) via a raw socket?? If you want to send emails, I would suggest using an email library such as PHPMailer which already knows how to communicate via SMTP. Or are you trying to build your own SMTP client for fun / education? I can't think of another reason why you'd be doing it.

Comment: @ADyson, I am using such library only. There is something wrong at server level of which I am not sure about

Comment: Sorry I don't understand? If you're using PHPMailer already then why are you trying to use fsockopen? it doesn't make sense. Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: by checking error logs what I get is the above error. I am actually not trying to use fsockopen

Comment: "I am actually not trying to use fsockopen"...then why did you use fsockopen in your code?? Sorry you are not making much sense, I'm afraid. Try and explain again.

Comment: fsockopen is being used by 3rd part extension. I am just getting the error. I am not trying to connect. The error is being recived with the 3rd party as well my code(Just for testing)

Comment: @ADyson the extension is 'https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp'

Comment: I see. That makes more sense. You should add all that information to your question, because it's pretty unclear otherwise.

Comment: It's not something I have direct experience of unfortunately, so unless someone comes along with a better suggestion I would say you could start [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=AWS+ubuntu+gmail+smtp) to learn more about it and/or get more ideas for fixes or workarounds.

Comment: @ADyson, I will update. the question. However fsockopen works without SSL.

Comment: Thanks. When you say "without ssl", what exact connection did you make which succeeded? Are you talking about the TLS connection which is commented out?

Comment: Yes it is giving error with both the statements. Is it something related to SSL verification?

Comment: "Yes it is giving error with both the statements"..., no i asked you what connection you used which **succeeded** in the case where you say it "works without SSL". If both those lines of code failed, then that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It _could_ be to do with certificate verification yes. Or it could just be that the port isn't open outbound.

Comment: @ADyson, please check the question update. I have solved it. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks but don't write the answer in the question! Write it in the answers section below, then people can vote on it, and it becomes searchable. You have enough reputation points to understand how this site works, I would hope :-)